# Why does running `pgrep` from npx or npm scripts give a different answer?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, grep, pid

Specifically, if run `pgrep -f azurite` from the terminal when no processes matching "azurite" I get nothing back.

But if I run this via npx, `npx pgrep -f azurite` (again with no matching processes running), I get back a pid. I'm assuming this is the pid of the shortlived node process used to run the task, as it matches nothing in `ps aux`.

The outcome is the same if run from npm scripts in my package.json.

Why?

Can this be avoided?

Comment: I assume you get the PID from `npx pgrep -f azurite`.

Comment: @Cyrus I get an arbitrary PID, when I expect not to get one.

Comment: Why do you expect not to get one? You even explain why you're getting a result in your question - it's matching the process you're running.

Comment: @Shawn because I'm expecting to find the PID of processes matching "azurite", which isn't running - thus no PID should be returned

Comment: Do you know what the `-f` option to `pgrep` does?

Comment: @Shawn `-f  Match against full argument lists.  The default is to match against process names.` I need this because the azurite process is `node /panda/node_modules/.bin/azurite --silent --location /panda/.azurite --debug /panda/.azurite.log`

Comment: And what word do you think is present in the command line of the pgrep process (And/or the npx one)?

Comment: @Shawn "azurite"

Answer (score 2):

I think I reproduced your problem with this script `npx`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
ps -ef | grep azurite
pgrep -f azurite
```

When you call `./npx`, the `ps` only finds  `grep azurite` and `pgrep` finds nothing.
When you call `./npx azurate`, the result is

```
+ ps -ef
+ grep azurite
walter     142     9  0 17:17 tty1     00:00:00 /bin/bash ./npx azurite
walter     145   142  0 17:17 tty1     00:00:00 grep azurite
+ pgrep -f azurite
142
```

In this example the `pid` found is from the `npx` call.
With `pgrep azurite` (without `-f`) it might be fixed (I tested with another script `azurite`), but I do not know when it is given as an argument to a program.
You may need to use

```
ps -ef | awk '/[a]zurite/ {print $2}'
```